# @gorhom Bottom Sheet - Forwarded Ref is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

Im trying to implement this relatively popular bottom sheet in React Native by @gorhom.

My aim is to open the bottom sheet from another component. I've tried to follow this answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70719996/how-can-i-open-bottomsheetmodal-gorhom-bottom-sheet-in-different-component-u) .

As far as i am aware, the forwarding of the ref seems correct. However, when i check the console log of the element being pressed - it is returned as 'undefined'

Code below

**BottomSheetModalComponent**

```
export default function BottomSheetModalComponent({ref}) {

// ref
const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

// variables
const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

// callbacks
const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
  ref.current?.present();
}, []);
const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
  console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
}, []);

// renders
return (
  <BottomSheetModalProvider>
    <View>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={ref}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </View>
  </BottomSheetModalProvider>
);
};
```

**Location Component**

```
export default function LocationBar() {
   // Create Ref
  const userBottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  // Pass ref into the bottom sheet component
  <LocationBottomSheet ref={userBottomSheetRef} snapPoints={["30%"]}/>

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={styles.locationBar}>
          <Octicons style={styles.locationIcon} name="location" size={18} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {

            // LINE BELOW RETURNS AS UNDEFINED
            userBottomSheetRef.current?.present()

          }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '600'}}>{userLocation}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Ionicons style={styles.chevronIcon} name="chevron-down" size={12} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

##### Some things to note: I didn't this test, so you may have to fix some things, but the way it goes is mentioned below. Secondly, bottom sheet needs to be rendered, so you need to place it in return.

You need to use Forward Ref with useImperativeHandle, like this

```
export default const BottomSheetModalComponent = forwardRef((props,ref)=> {


// ref
const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

useImperativeHandle(ref,()=>({
presentModal:()=>ref.current?.present() 
})

// variables
const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

// callbacks
const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
  ref.current?.present();
}, []);
const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
  console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
}, []);

// renders
return (
  <BottomSheetModalProvider>
    <View>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={ref}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </View>
  </BottomSheetModalProvider>
);
});
```

Then use it in your component like this

```
export default function LocationBar() {
   // Create Ref
  const userBottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);


  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={styles.locationBar}>
          <Octicons style={styles.locationIcon} name="location" size={18} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            userBottomSheetRef.current?.presentModal()
          }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight: '600'}}>{userLocation}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Ionicons style={styles.chevronIcon} name="chevron-down" size={12} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <LocationBottomSheet ref={userBottomSheetRef} snapPoints={["30%"]}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am still getting undefined. The way i have my app setup is - Home Screen, Location Bar is a component on the Home Screen. BottomSheetModalComponent is also a separate component. Therefore, my aim is that when the component LocationBar is clicked, I would want the bottom sheet modal to open on the Home Screen. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Don't need another layer with useImperativeHandle. It works fine without it. Here is my example which I've tested.

```
const ActionSheet = forwardRef<BottomSheetModal, BottomSheetModalProps>((props, ref) => {
    const renderBackDrop = useCallback((props: BottomSheetBackdropProps) => {
        return (
            <BottomSheetBackdrop {...props} opacity={0.5} animatedIndex={{ value: 1 }} pressBehavior={"close"} />
        )
    }, []);

    return (
        <BottomSheetModal
            ref={ref}
            {...props}
            containerStyle={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 24,
                borderTopRightRadius: 24,
            }}
            backgroundStyle={{
                backgroundColor: colors.slate[100]
            }}
            backdropComponent={renderBackDrop}
        >
            {props.children}
        </BottomSheetModal>
    );
});
```

When you call it, it is as follows:

```
<ActionSheet 
                ref={bottomSheetModalRef} 
                snapPoints={snapPoints}
                onDismiss={closeBottomSheet}
            >
                <View><Text>Test</Text></View>
            </ActionSheet>
```

For the BottomSheetBackdrop to close in Android (iOS works fine without it) just add the GestureHandlerRootView as per following example to your starting point file i.e. App.tsx / index.js

```
const App = () => {    
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <GestureHandlerRootView className='flex-1'>
              <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                  {
                    IS_ANDROID && <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={'transparent'} barStyle={colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
                  }
                  <RootNavigation />
              </BottomSheetModalProvider>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </Provider>    
      <Toast config={toastConfig} />
    </>
  );
};
```